# simplex and power set

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, terminology, simplicial-stuff

I read the following:

Let $M$ be a set.  The simplex on $M$ is the set of all subsets of $M$; we denote this by
$\Delta_M$. We will sometimes refer to the elements of $M$ as vertices of $\Delta_M$.
A simplicial complex on $M$ is a subset of $\Delta_M$ which is closed under the taking
of subsets. If $\Gamma$ is a simplicial complex on $M$ and $F\in \Gamma$, we say that $F$ is a face of $\Gamma$. We require that simplicial complexes be nonempty; that is, the empty set must always be a face.

Is $\Delta_M$ what we call the **full** simplex? and isn't this simply $2^M$ the power set of $M$? What do we mean by closed under the taking, do we mean closed under **union** operation? is this what we call an abstract simplicial complex and how does this relate to the geometric notion of simplicial complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That definition seems to assume that $M$ is a finite set, since the members of a simplicial complex are normally required to be finite subsets of the underlying set. Yes, $\Delta_M$ is the power set of $M$. If $\Gamma\subseteq\Delta_M$, $\Gamma$ is *closed under the taking of subsets* if and only if $X\subseteq Y\in\Gamma$ implies that $X\in\Gamma$.

More generally, if $\mathscr{A}$ is any collection of sets, we say that $\mathscr{A}$ is closed under the taking of subsets (or simply *closed under taking subsets*) if every subset of a member of $\mathscr{A}$ is also a member of $\mathscr{A}$. Yet another way to say this is that for each $A\in\mathscr{A}$, $\wp(A)\subset\mathscr{A}$. Unions are not involved here.

If $K$ is a geometric simplicial complex, let $M$ be the set of its vertices; we’ll build an associated abstract simplicial complex $\Gamma$ on $M$. Each $d$-dimensional face of $K$ has $d+1$ vertices; let that set of $d+1$ vertices belong to $\Gamma$. For example, if $K$ consists of a tetrahedron with vertices $v_1,v_2,v_3$, and $v_4$, a triangle with vertices $v_1,v_2$, and $v_5$, and a segment with vertices $v_5$ and $v_6$, $M=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5,v_6\}$, and

$$\begin{align*}\Gamma&=\Big\{\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\},\{v_1,v_2,v_3\},\{v_1,v_2,v_4\},\{v_1,v_3,v_4\},\{v_2,v_3,v_4\},\\
&\quad\;\;\,\{v_1,v_2\},\{v_1,v_3\},\{v_1,v_4\},\{v_2,v_3\},\{v_2,v_4\},\{v_3,v_4\},\{v_1\},\{v_2\},\\
&\quad\;\;\,\{v_3\},\{v_4\},\varnothing,\{v_1,v_2,v_5\},\{v_1,v_5\},\{v_2,v_5\},\{v_5\},\{v_5,v_6\},\{v_6\}\Big\}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Going in the other direction, I’ll quote [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex#Geometric_realization):

> If $K$ is [a] finite [abstract simplicial complex], then we can describe $|K|$ more simply. Choose an embedding of the vertex set of $K$ as an affinely independent subset of some Euclidean space $\Bbb R^N$ of sufficiently high dimension $N$. Then any face $X \in K$ can be identified with the geometric simplex in $\Bbb R^N$ spanned by the corresponding embedded vertices. Take $|K|$ to be the union of all such simplices.

(Here $|K|$ is the geometric realization of $K$.)

Comment: you mean $X\subseteq Y\in \Gamma$ implies $X\in \Gamma$.

Comment: @palio: Fixed; thanks!